# Sublime Text 2 (OSX) lags when editing a remote file

Tags: sublimetext2, virtualbox

When I first start editing a file in SublimeText 2 remotely (hosting a git repo on a VirtualBox-ed copy of Ubuntu) saves are speedy as expected. After having the file/connection open for a while it starts to lock up every time I save, forcing me to wait 3-4 seconds for the save to go through to the remote connection.

How do I solve this lag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by unmounting/remounting the connection to my remote repo directory. After doing this, I was able to save with no lag or waiting.